# Java mail fails to connect to port

Tags: java, email, port

I'm trying send email over Java, and I've already done this before, but the ISP that I'm using now seems to have blocked all the ports as I have this code:

```
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587"); 
        // tried props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
        //props.put("mail.smtp.port", "8889"); For my personal host setting   
        props.put("mail.smtp.timout", "10000");
```

The problem is I keep getting `Could not connect to port error`, so in case the ISP blocks all the ports, is there any possible way to send emails or just in case, could be something wrong with my approach. (it works with some ISPs but not with the one that I need to run the code on)

Comment: Have you tried 465 with ssl ?

Comment: @JorgeCampos: yes still the port error

Comment: Contact your current ISP. I do not believe this can be a programming issue if the code works elsewhere.

Comment: Have you tried to use telnet, tocheck if you do not have a problem with firewall?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one if it helps (for Gmail).

Some of the below lines may not be required, but I have not tested each line just used these key-value pairs and working fine.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.user", senderEmailAddress);
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", port_port);
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

    //SecurityManager security = System.getSecurityManager();
```

For my local Email I have used this one (non SSL)

```
System.setProperty("sun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation","true");
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.user", senderEmailAddress);
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", host_name); //for me : mail.mydomain.com
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", smtp_port); //mine is "25"
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    //props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");        
    //props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", smtp_port);
    //props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    //props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

//SecurityManager security = System.getSecurityManager();
```